# What Drivers need for Intel Device 4c8e Integrated Graphics on ubuntu 18.04.06 LTS

Tags: intel-graphics

I have a new desktop Hardware with CPU 11th GEN Intel Core i7-11700k LGA 1200 model which also have integrated Graphics, which i'm unable to use for computing.Below are the findings  on my system.

```
#inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 4c8a
           Display Server: N/A drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           tty size: 150x38 Advanced Data: N/A out of X

#cat /sys/devices/pci0000\:00/0000\:00\:02.0/enable 
0
```

Please help me how to enable the graphics and use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think they aren't working?  If there is no dedicated GPU and you are using a desktop, then the iGPU is working. The iGPU is a feature of your CPU. It is not a separate processor for computing. If you believe you're still missing something, edit your question. You should tell us what flavor of Ubuntu you are using. Also include the make/model of any dedicsy GPUs. You also need to give a clearer description of what you are trying to do and the details about the exact problems you face. "unable to use for computing" is too vague

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. my intension of computing is that iam unable to use Openvino, Intel Quick sync for encoding or decoding a video, even though i have full software stack which are required, and they are working with other system

Comment: You can't do it at all? If so, describe the steps you are taking and describe the behavior of your device. How is it not working? Is there an error? Are options grayed out or not selectable, etc? Or is the supposed problem that you can't explicitly use the GPU for compute? Because as I mentioned in the last comment, you don't really have a GPU if all you have is the iGPU. You only have a CPU.